# Blackberry - loading bar at the bottom of screen

Tags: layout, blackberry, user-interface

Facebook and twitter have a loading bar at the bottom of the screen that can dissapear if the page have finished loading.

What field or layout manager that implemented dissapear thing. Are that custom field/manager? what it is called?

thanks for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve what Facebook or Twitter did with 2 VerticalFieldManger and 1 Field (**loadingBar**). Customize your **loadingBar** as you wish.

[**Check this layout**](http://i53.tinypic.com/2z7raxe.png)

Use 1st VerticalFieldManger as **parentManager**.
and 2nd VerticalFieldManger as **contenManager**.

Make **contentManager** scrollable and add functionality for changing its height.

Adjust the height of the **contentManager** when the **parentManager** add the **loadingBar** to it or remove the **loadingBar** from it.

Comment: Thanks for u answer. i got your point.
The loading bar is not a new screen or dialog because we can still interact with the contentManager. How do i can achieve that? is like settitle but at the bottom. thanks

Comment: settitle only add contents on the top of the screen. We can use any Field object i.e. ButtonField, LabelField or other customized Field as loadingBar. After we have our loadingBar prepared, then we can simply add it to the parent manager. But for positioning the loading bar at the bottom we may have to override the sublayout method of the parent manager and there we have to manually set the position of the loading bar using setpositionchild() method.