# VerticalFieldManager not Scrolling for jre5

Tags: blackberry

I am using jre 5 and a 9550 simulator in my system.. I have a problem in my app with scrolling the `VerticalFieldManager`..

I am calling a new Screen from my MainScreen java file..

The Code is like...

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        try
        {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new CustomDialog());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Dialog.alert("loading Error");
        }
    }
});
```

And that CustomDialog.java is like...

```
public final class CustomDialog extends MainScreen
{
    LabelField title, message;
    HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
    VerticalFieldManager vfm;
    GridFieldManager gfm;

    public CustomDialog()
    {
        super(Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);

        hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_LEFT);
        title = new LabelField("hello User",FIELD_HCENTER)
        {
            protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                graphics.setColor(Color.BROWN);
                super.paint(graphics);
            };
        };
        title.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 20));
        hfm.add(title);
        add(hfm);

        vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
        message = new LabelField("my text");//Actually a long text..
        vfm.add(message);
        VerticalFieldManager tmp = new VerticalFieldManager();
        tmp.add(vfm);
        add(tmp);
    }
}
```

The message is displaying in the screen, but it is not scrolling..
Actually, the message is a long text, and i want to do scrolling for that `VerticalFieldManager`..

How can i get it scrolling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `VerticalFieldManager` scrolling, add focusable `NullField` object before and after the `LabelField`.

```java
vfm.add(New NullField());
vfm.add(message);
vfm.add(New NullField());
```

It will now scrolls from bottom to top of the Label at once and vice versa. To get rid of this problem use `RichTextField`. It is the best choice for displaying long text. It itself handles scrolling vertically (line by line) and horizontally (character by character).

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned it in answer. But it solves the scrolling problem. To solve '"but it just shows the first part of text and the last part"' you have many options. You can split your text into several lines and add each of them into a LabelField. See @rfsk2010 's answer.

Comment: Just do something like this, vfm.add(new RichTextField(text));

Comment: Yes, then add a LabelField (title) and RichTextField (content) on another VerticalFieldManager.

Comment: i had done it.. But think still to improve it a little bit.. I need the button to be static in the bottom of screen(which is now only if i scroll down to the end of my richtextfield)..
Also, the CustomDialog screen is closing when ecs is pressed.. can i disable that default_close??
looking forward for ur valuable reply..

Comment: to disable default close on back menu press override `public boolean onClose() {return true;}` on your PopupScreen implementation. And you can check following answer for static field manager (that can hold a button) in the bottom.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7174143/431639

Comment: i had put the preferedheight, preferedwidth and the layout for the message. Now the buttons can be shown at the bottom..
but it again caused one problem dear.. when i scrolls the message, the screen shows blank.. only the content which appears on the screen can be viewed. all the rest is not showing while scrolling..

Answer (score 0):

Rupaks answer will work for scrolling if the text is not too long,. But if the text is like several pages, for example EULA or terms and conditions, It will jump from the start page to the last page.

You can solve that by using the following code were i have replaced the labelField by editField.

```
                    LabelField title;
                    EditField message;
                    HorizontalFieldManager hfm;
                    VerticalFieldManager vfm;
                    GridFieldManager gfm; 
                    final MainScreen screen=new MainScreen();
                    hfm = new HorizontalFieldManager(Field.FIELD_LEFT);
                    title = new LabelField("hello User",FIELD_HCENTER)
                    {
                        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
                            graphics.setColor(Color.BROWN);
                            super.paint(graphics);
                        };
                    };
                    title.setFont(getFont().derive(Font.BOLD, 20));
                    hfm.add(title);
                    add(hfm);

                    vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
                    message = new EditField("","long text");

                    vfm.add(message);
                    VerticalFieldManager tmp = new VerticalFieldManager();
                    tmp.add(vfm);
                    add(tmp);
```

Comment: you can create a non editable edit field as  EditField txt = new EditField(Field.FOCUSABLE | Field.READONLY)

Comment: got the solution as rupak said dear.. the editfield showed the keyboard and can edit my text..

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    super(Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE|VERTICAL_SCROLL);
```

isteadOf

```
    super(Screen.DEFAULT_CLOSE);
```

and

```
    vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(VERTICAL_SCROLL);
```

isteadOf

```
    vfm = new VerticalFieldManager(Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL);
```